# Problems with the if statement in C

Tags: c

```
int main() {
printf ("Welcome in Lorempipsuland.h\n");
printf ("Choose one oh the paths:\n");
printf ("1-Nerd programmer's Rocky Mountains\n");
printf ("2-Olografic Banshee's Lakes\n");
c = getchar();
if (c == 1) {
    printf ("You entered in the Nerd programmer's Rocky Mountains\n");
    printf ("Oh no, you met the solitaire programmer, do you want combat? Yes(1) or Not(2)?\n");
    a = getchar();
    if (a == 1)  {
        printf ("You decided to fight, PREPARE!\n");
    }
    else if (a == 2) {
        printf ("Coward!, but now go away, we have to walk lot");
    }
}
else if (c == 2) {
    printf ("You entered in Holographic Banshee's lakes\n");
    printf ("Oh no, that's an Holographic Banshee!\n");
}
```

I'm on kali linux terminal and I have problems because when the terminal execute the code, reads all the if conditions until it arrives at the first if, then the terminal returns to root kali, not executing others if and else if conditions.

Can you help me please?

Comment: You need to compile C code first. A terminal (I asume you mean the shell) does not run C code. If that is not what you mean, learn [ask] and clarify. Also format your code properly. Pick a formatting style and follow it consistently.

Comment: i compiled C code but it doesn't run all if instances, just the first.

Comment: `if` is a statement, not an instance - very different things. Using incorrect terms is a good way to be missunderstood. But that is no the only problem with your question. Would you kindly please take the tour and read the provided link?

Comment: yes i know but in english i can't do difference

Comment: "Lorem**pi**psu_land"? Wouldn't that be "Loremipsum..."? Oh, and `c` is undefined. Your code does not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem, you are comparing the input against a number and not againt the typed character. So instead of

```
if (c == 1)
```

you need

```
if (c == '1')
```

The next problem is that (usually) when you enter `'1'` you also press `Enter` and that leaves a `newline` in the input. So when you read the *next* response, that `newline` is read instead of the next response. In this example, I have dealt with it by writing a function to get a response and which ignores any `newline`. Note too, I have used `int` type for the key responses, because that is the return value from library function `getchar()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getakey(void)
{
    int ch;
    do {
        ch = getchar();
    } while (ch == '\n');           // ignores newline
    return ch;
}

int main(void)
{
    int c, a;
    printf ("Welcome in Lorempipsuland.h\n");
    printf ("Choose one oh the paths:\n");
    printf ("1-Nerd programmer's Rocky Mountains\n");
    printf ("2-Olografic Banshee's Lakes\n");
    c = getakey();
    if (c == '1') {
        printf ("You entered in the Nerd programmer's Rocky Mountains\n");
        printf ("Oh no, hai incontrato un solitario programmatore infuriato perchè il codice riporta un errore fatale, hai 1000 di salute, vuoi combattere?\n");
        printf ("Yes(1) or Not(2)?\n");
        a = getakey();
        if (a == '1')  {
            printf ("You decided to fight, PREPARE!\n");
        }
        else if (a == '2') {
            printf ("Coward!, but now go away, we have to walk lot\n");
        }
    }
    else if (c == '2') {
        printf ("You entered in Holographic Banshee's lakes\n");
        printf ("Oh no, that's an Holographic Banshee!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i understood my errors ;)

Answer (score 3):

That is not how you compare `char`.

---

This is how you compare `char`

```
(c == '1')
```

Comment: I don't understand . We don't know type of vairable `c`  and `getchar` returns an `int` . Then where is the question about comparing `char` ? Normally , and correctly `c` should be an `int` not `char` .

Comment: Actually, as `char` is an integer type, this is very well the correct way. It's just the value `2` is not what OP actually wants to compare with, but the integer value of the _character_ `'2'`.

Comment: @Olaf `'2'` *is* evaluated as `int`

Comment: i tried in the same way you told and it works, now the terminal goes until the second if statement, so it write:
    You entered in the Nerd programmer's Rocky Mountains
Oh no, hai incontrato un solitario programmatore vuoi combattere Si(1) o No(2)?

Comment: user3597474 did you look at the second point in the answer from @Vatine? You still have a `newline` in the input buffer.

Comment: @WeatherVane: No wonder as it is an [_integer character constant_](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4p2). I thought "integer value of the character '2'" made that clear already.

Comment: @user3597474: This is an english speaking site.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of problems with the code...

- You're comparing the entered character to numbers. This works (chars are basically smal ints), but doesn't do what you expect. The character with he numeric value 1 is Control-A
- Unless you've flipped stdin to non-buffering, your program won't have any character to read, until you press the enter/return key and at that point, you will have more than one character (prompt pops up, you type 1, then press enter, the first if is consulted (but at the moment, nothing matches, since you entered `'1'`, not `1`)) waiting to be read, the character you're after and a newline. You could work around this by having an intermediate function that reads and ignores "whitespace" (spaces, tabs, newlines, ...).

Comment: ok, this solved my question, but now it arrives at the second if statement and then it stop, and don't ask me if i want to combat or not.

Comment: @user3597474: Please learn to use a debugger. SO is no remote debugging service.

Comment: @user3597474 That is (probably) because the second `getchar()` returns a `'\n'` (as vaguely hinted to in my second point).